# Homogeneous spaces which are not torus bundle over flag manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, projective-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

For a compact semisimple Lie group $G$, what is an example of a homogeneous space of $G$ which is not a torus bundle over a [generalized flag manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety) of $G$. Examples for $SU(N)$ would be of most interest.

Comment: How about $SU(N)$ modulo a finite subgroup, e.g., the group of $N$th roots of unity?

Comment: I guess a better example of a finite subgroup is the group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ of permutation matrices.

Comment: It would help if you were to define "generalized" flag manifolds. The issue of course is which subgroups of $G$ you allow to quotient by. The standard definition is to use parabolic subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Yes I mean parabolic - I've included now a link in the definition.

Comment: In that case, $\mathfrak{S}_N\subset SU(N)$ is a counterexample.  It is easier to see if you consider the quotient by a bigger group $H=U(1)^{N-1}\cdot \mathfrak{S}_N$, where $U(1)^{N-1}$ is the group of diagonal matrices.  The quotient of $SU(N)$ by the group of diagonal matrices is the total flag variety.  The further quotient by $\mathfrak{S}_n$ does not admit a $SU(N)$-equivariant map to any flag variety (other than the one-point space).  For $N=2$, $SU(N)/H$ is equivalent to the quotient of the flag variety $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by the map $[z,w]\mapsto[\overline{w},-\overline{z}]$.

Comment: I just realized, $\mathfrak{S}_N$ is a subgroup of $U(N)$ whose intersection with $SU(N)$ is the normal subgroup $\mathfrak{A}_N$, the alternating group.  So please change every instance of $\mathfrak{S}_N$ to $\mathfrak{A}_N$.  That means the first examples as above will occur for $N=3$, since $\mathfrak{A}_2$ is trivial.

Comment: $SU(3) / SO(3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to summarize the common feature of both Allen's example and my example: there are many Lie subgroups $H$ of $G$ that are contained in no proper parabolic subgroup.  Some examples arise from the fact that a proper subgroup of a parabolic may have a normalizer that is not contained in the subgroup; the example $H$ that I intended was the normalizer in $SU(N)$ of a maximal torus $U(1)^{N-1}$.  But there are also connected subgroups that are contained in no proper parabolic subgroup, e.g., the intersection of $SU(N)$ with an algebraic subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Another example that I particularly like is the image of the group homomorphism $\rho:SU(2)\to SU(N)$ associated to the $N$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)$.  You can think of $SU(N)/\rho(SU(2))$ as a parameter space for real rational normal curves in $\mathbb{RP}^{N-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

It is like most of them. Are spheres any good for you?

You need some complex and/or algebraic structure to make it into a torus bundle (cf. Borel-Remmert Theorem). In general, let $T$ be the maximal torus of $G$. Then the flag manifold is $G/T$. If you take $G/H$ where $T$ does not contain $H$, the chances are you will have no fibration of $G/H$ over flags.

Comment: By flag manifold I meant generalized flag manifold, for example complex projective space, over which the sphere is circle bundle.

Comment: Odd-dimensional sphere is a circle bundle. Even-dimensional sphere is not.

Answer (score 3):

Any non-trivial torus bundle has Euler characteristic 0. Thus if a homogeneous space $G/H$ is not a generalized flag manifold and has non-zero Euler characteristic, it is not a torus bundle over a generalized flag manifold. This includes all even-dimensional spheres starting with $S^4$, as suggested by Bugs Bunny, and Allen Knutson's ${\rm SU}(3)/{\rm SO}(3)$.